# Problem with OpenID on Android

Tags: bug, status-norepro, mobile-web, stack-exchange-openid

When I try to login with StackExchange OpenID on my Android phone I get following response:

> [image]

My device is Samsung S3 Mini, Android version 4.1.2, I use Google Chrome.

I may also add that when I try again I get:

> [image]

Comment: Wait... are you using the app, or just browsing via your mobile device? If so, what device and what browser?

Comment: I similarly get the second (not the first) trying to login either on the stock browser or on Dolphin, running on an HTC Thunderbolt with Android 4.0.4.  Neither browser has cookies blocked or plugins installed.  The phone is not rooted, so adblock is neither installed nor running.

Comment: No issues using my Android 4.0.4, Android 4.4.2 mobile(s). Chromium, Firefox, and even the App works for me. Hmmm, did you do the usual "delete cookies and cache" dance? (I guess you already did, but asking doesn't hurt,)

Comment: Yes. I did. Done it again to be sure, same result.

Comment: Same here. Stock Android 2.2.3 browser. Meta let me login because it has the option to sign in directly on meta. The EE se redirects those to openid.stackexchange.com where the problem is. Been like that for a long time. Please fix!

Comment: On an iPhone 4, once I enter the openid user name and password, it redirects me to the electronics.stackexchange.com website. On android, it does not. It goes to https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login/submit and gives that page not found error.

Comment: Where are you trying to log in to? What site?

Comment: Android 4.1.1, Chrome, Dolphin and stock browsers. Logging in to meta.stackexchange.com - no repro.

Comment: Reinstalled Android - it works now.